# Data Saved Twice in MongoDB

Tags: ajax, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a form to add newCompany, I send data using AJAX like so:
[image: Ajax function]

And here is the post route: 
[image: POST route in the back-end]

And here is the company model: 
[image]

The problem is, when I add new company the data inserted twice, the first one is 12 fields without the image name!! and the second one is empty object! like so:
[image]

I have no idea and I gonna lose my mind!
Help please!

Comment: please just copy and past you code then use cmd/ctrl + k. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I ran into this same dilemma with saving form data into mongoose with images involved....

Answer (score 1):

you call `res.redirect('/company/create')` upon save, which sends HTTP302 to the client.  The client then triggers the same route a second time.  Try performing the redirect on the client side, after your `$.ajax()` request completes.

Comment: Your comment makes sense.
I edited the Ajax call to 
`success: function (data, response) {
                    window.location.href = response.redirect;`
and I removed the `res.redirect('/company/create')` from the route! 
but It doesn't work also ! !

Comment: and even if I changed the redirect to the home to avoid recall the same route twice like so `res.redirect('/home');` , also the data inserted twice full object and empty object!

Answer (score 0):

Look this is because you are redirecting your response to **company/create**

```
router.post('/company/create', function(req, res, next){

  var newCompany = new Company({
    name: req.body.name,
    address: req.body.address,
    city: req.body.city,
    country: req.body.country,
    .
    .
    .
    .
  });

    Company.save(newCompany, function(err, response){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }

      res.location('/home');
      res.redirect('/home');
    });
});
```

If it doesn't work, let us see your model. the problem may be there

Comment: It doesn't work also, I think the error is in the ajax method, because when I comment it out, only one empty object sent to the back-end!

Comment: you will find a screenshot of the model in the Question above.

Comment: add a console.log(req.body) in the app.post, send the ajax again. That way you make sure the ajax is not sending data twice.

Comment: sebastian salamanca the redirect is a get request and there is a get handler for that particular url as well

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and i reached this post following your link posted at Udemy.com Q&A board on lecture 37 of the course we're following.

the solution for this problem handle the 'submit' event NOT click event for the button, it looks like the code get executed in response to our wish to handle click event, and then it does execute the natural behavior (and execute the route handler again)

here is the complete validate.js file, just replace the 'click' with 'submit' and this should solve the problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#register').on('submit',function(e){

       var name     = $.trim($('#name').val());
       var address  = $.trim($('#address').val());
       var city     = $.trim($('#city').val());
       var country  = $.trim($('#country').val());
       var sector   = $.trim($('#sector').val());
       var website  = $.trim($('#website').val());
       var img      = $.trim($('#upload-input').val());

       var isValid = true;

       if(name == ''){

           isValid = false;
           $('#errorMsg1').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Company name can\'t be empty</div>');
       }

       if(address == ''){

           isValid = false;
           $('#errorMsg2').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">address can\'t be empty</div>');
       }

       if(city == ''){

           isValid = false;
           $('#errorMsg3').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">City can\t be empty</div>');
       }

       if(country == ''){

           isValid = false;
           $('#errorMsg4').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Country can\'t be empty</div>');
       }

       if(sector == ''){

           isValid = false;
           $('#errorMsg5').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Sector can\'t be empty</div>');
       }

       if(country == ''){

           isValid = false;
           $('#errorMsg6').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Website can\'t be empty</div>');
       }

       if(isValid == false){

           return false;

       }else{

           var newCompany = {
               name:        name,
               address:     address,
               city:        city,
               country:     country,
               sector:      sector,
               website:     website,
               img:         img
           };

           $.ajax({
               url:         '/company/create',
               type:        'POST',
               data:        newCompany,
               success:     function(){

                   $('#name').val('');
                   $('#address').val('');
                   $('#city').val('');
                   $('#country').val('');
                   $('#sector').val('');
                   $('#website').val('');
                   $('#upload-input').val('');
               }
           });

       }

   }) 
});
```

Comment: but when I checked the network tab post happens only once